# Are there any sets that cannot be constructed using the symbols $\{$ and $\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

It seems to me all sets in mathematics can be constructed via these two symbols only. For instance, the natural numbers are defined as $0 = \varnothing = \{\}, 1 = \{0\}$, $2 = \{0, 1\}, 3 = \{0, 1, 2\}$ and so on.  From this it follows that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and even $\mathbb{C}$ can be constructed using $\{$ and $\}$ only. Are there any sets that cannot be, in theory, constructed via just these two symbols?

Comment: It *really* depends on what you mean by constructed here. How would you say $\Bbb R$ can be constructed this way? This construction as far as I am aware is more or less the foundation of the principle of mathematical induction (read: $\Bbb N$) and so I wouldn't expect this to generalize to $\Bbb R$...

Answer (score 2):

No, the axiom of regularity essentially tells us that given a set $x$, there is a finite sequence $x_0=x,x_n=\varnothing$ such that $x_n\in\ldots\in x_0$.

A difference way to look at it would be to see that in $\sf ZF$ we can show that the universe is really constructed from the empty set by iterating the power set. So essentially the answer is negative. Although it should be exercised with caution since the set of all natural numbers would be one that has increasingly more "opening braces", but there is no infinite sequence of closing braces. This might coincide and might not with the notion of "construct" people hold in their heads.

Comment: Another way of saying it: the membership relation restricted to any set $A$ gives a tree $T_A$ with no infinite paths. Since the tree is well founded, we can associate each node with a (possibly infinite) expression, recursively, starting at the dead ends. If we associate each dead end with the expression $\{\}$ and recursively associate each internal node $B$ with $\{ X \}$ where $X$ is the concatenation of the expressions associated to members of $B$, then the root node $A$ will be associated with an expression (possibly infinite) using only $\{$ and $\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful comment, Carl!